# Sequence of Concave Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(t)$ be a sequence of concave functions (i.e. $-f_n(t)$ is a convex function) on an interval of the form $(-c,c)$, and suppose $g$ is any function $(-c,c) \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $\liminf_n f_n(t) \geq g(t)$ for every $t$, $\lim f_n(0) = g(0)$ and  that all the $f_n$ and $g$ are differentiable at $0$.

I would like to show under these conditions that $\lim f_n'(0) = g'(0)$.

To this end, I have been able to show that the function $\tilde{f}(t):= \liminf_n(t)$ is also a concave function, and I sense that from here I should be able to prove it, but I'm not very good at analysis so I'm missing something.

It's worth noting that the condition $\liminf f_n(t) \geq g(t)$ implies that $\lim f_n'(0) \geq  g'(0)$, so maybe we can prove the reverse inequality?

Comment: What is the relation between $c$ and $a$?

Comment: Oops. Typo. They should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Write (for small $h$) $g(h)=g(0) + g'(0)h + o(h) \le \liminf_n f_n(h).$ But the $f_n$ are differentiable at $0$ and concave, so we have $f_n(h)\le f_n(0)+f_n'(0)h.$  Put these together and get 
$$g(0)+g'(0)h+o(h)\le \liminf_n (f_n(0)+f_n'(0)h )=\lim_nf_n(0)+\liminf_n f_n'(0)h $$ and
$$ g'(0)h+o(h)\le \liminf_n f_n'(0)h.$$

Now let $h\searrow0$, to get $g'(0)\le \liminf_n f_n'(0).$  But when $h\nearrow 0$, the inequality is reversed, and we get $g'(0)\ge\limsup_n f_n'(0).$  So $\lim_n f_n'(0) = g'(0)$ as desired.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, but I am skeptical of one thing - doesn't Taylor's theorem require the function to be at least differentiable in a neighborhood of the point? I am aware the derivative need not be continuous since here you have only used a first order approximation, but still, I am stuck on this point.

Comment: Typo correction: For $f $to be differentiable at $0$ means no more and no less than: there exists a number (call it $f′(0)$ such that$ (f(h)−f(0))/h−f′(0)=o(1)$, as we all learned in school. Clear fractions, and you get $f(h)=f(0)+f′(0)h+o(h)$, which is the form I used above. That is, this use of Taylor approximation is exactly equivalent to the differentiability assumptions you posed.